# Autocomplete using JQuery with Ajax method in c# ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have added the method from ajax for autocomplete in my textbox(In Popup-Container). And data from SQL using WebMethod in `ascx.cs` file and below code has no error/exception but still didn't get output. I have tried `AutoCompleteExtender` also, but that also couldn't return any result (mainly `GetCompletionList` method is not called).

In EditUserSheet.ascx

```
$("#txtStudName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "EditUserSheet.ascx/GetCompletionList",
                data: "{'stdName':'" + document.getElementById('txtStudName').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result)
                {
                    alert("No Match");
                }
            });
        }
});
```

and TextBox ID = txtStudName

In EditUserSheet.ascx.cs

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string stdName)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AlexaDB;Initial Catalog=Students;User ID=***;Password=***"))
    {
        List<string> StudentNames = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_SearchUserName", sqlconn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", stdName);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                StudentNames.Add(dt.Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString());
            }

            sqlconn.Close();
            return StudentNames;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            LoggingHandler.WriteLog(ex, TraceEventType.Error);
        }
        return StudentNames;
    }
}
```

Nothing shown in my textbox. Actually I expect when I start typing in my textbox, it wants to retrieve the list of data related that.

Comment: Are u sure u are getting value in `data` field? I think its better to get value from `request` object like this `data: "{'stdName':'" + request.term + "'}",`